# Vue - Passing prop array through vue component causes not defined error

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to pass an array of dates through to my component, but it keeps throwing

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "dates" is not defined on the instance
   but referenced during render
```

I don't understand why, as I'm receiving the variable in props, I'm using laravel btw.
I can use props like this if I reference them in the vue instance on a my app.js file, but I cant get my php variables into that file so there's no point .

**Base:**

HTML:

```
 <div class="graph">
            <linegraph :dates="dates"></linegraph>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
var dates = {
        monday: '{{ $monday }}',
        tuesday: '{{ $tuesday }}',
        wednsday: '{{ $wednsday }}',
        thursday: '{{ $thursday }}',
        friday: '{{ $friday }}',
        saturday: '{{ $saturday }}',
        sunday: '{{ $sunday }}'
    }
```

**Component:**

Template:

```
    <div class="chart_card">
        <h2>{{ dates }}</h2>
        <div>
            <GChart
                :settings="{ packages: ['corechart'] }"
                type="LineChart"
                :data="chartData"
                :options="chartOptions"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
   export default {
    name: 'linegraph',
    props: ['dates'],
    data() {
      return {

        } 
    },
    components: {
        GChart
    },
    methods: {

    },
  };
```

Vue instance startup:

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');



window.Vue = require('vue');

import Vue from 'vue';

import InstantSearch from 'vue-instantsearch';

Vue.use(InstantSearch);

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i);
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default));


// DASHBOARD
Vue.component('linegraph', require('./components/dashboard/line_graph.vue').default);

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {

    },
});
```

Any help would be amazing! Thankyou :)

Comment: Try changing props to `props: { dates: { type: Object, required: true} }` and see what happens. Also can you confirm `dates` object is being formed properly in parent component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: rather than creating a variable for your dates, go to the place where you do this:

```
<div class="graph">
    <linegraph :dates="dates"></linegraph>
</div>
```

And replace `:dates="dates"` with this:

```
:dates="{{ json_encode([
    'monday' => $monday,
    'tuesday' => $tuesday,
    'wednesday' => $wednesday,
    'thursday' => $thursday,
    'friday' => $friday,
    'saturday' => $saturday,
    'sunday' => $sunday
]) }}"
```

Comment: Thankyou! Idk wtf is wrong with my code but this works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define variables inside the data method to make it accessible in HTML part of vue component.

If data is coming from some backend like PHP, you can create a variable in data and assign it the value from backend.

```
data () {
  return {
    dates: []
  }
},
```

and in mounted or whichever hook you are using to access the data

```
methods: {
  fetchData (datesFromBK) {
    this.dates = datesFromBK
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the server-rendered JS part (with the variables from PHP) **before** initializing Vue instance on `chart_card`.

**OR**

Template:

```
<div v-if="dates" class="chart_card">
    <h2>{{ dates }}</h2>
</div>
```

*(I hope this `h2` is just for debugging, since this will not render the list of dates, just some trash ;))*